# Is it possible to change the background color of a Spyder Python console?

Tags: console, background-color, spyder

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the background color of a Python regular console in Spyder. I know Spyder already allows to change between two colors: Black or white. But is there any way to get a different color besides those?

Comment: FYI, The current accepted answer is not correct, as the other answer clearly indicates the way of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) For Spyder versions *lesser* than **3.2.0**, there is no way to change the background to a different color, sorry.

For versions greater or equal to **3.2.0**, the Python console is completely removed, so this no longer applies.

Finally, since **3.2.0** our *IPython* consoles follow the same color scheme of the Editor without any additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks Carlos for your reply. Well... this may be a cool feature to add in future releases.  I've been trying to pick a color scheme for the whole IDE that be easy for my eyes.

Comment: We'll add the same color scheme of the Editor to the IPython console in spyder 3.1. The Python console will be removed in Spyder 4.0, so we don't plan to add any more features to it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Can you update/delete this answer? It is out of date.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Go to "Tools" and "Preferences" and then "Syntax coloring". There are a handful of preset themes. There is also an option to create a custom theme if you don't find any of the defaults aesthetically pleasing (I know I didn't).